# Where does Python Pip Install Wheel puts the files

Tags: python, pip

I just wanted to know...where does the command

```
pip install sample.whl
```

puts its files?  i just need to check some script.
I am no Python expert and I just wanted to check on something.

let me know if this is a duplicate question..sorry if my question is a bit basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library files will install to the site-packages directory, and the location of this directory depends on your Python installation - check [*What's the deal with "purelib" vs. "platlib"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#what-s-the-deal-with-purelib-vs-platlib) section of PEP 427 to see more about that.

For the typical cases files will install to purelib path, the location of which you can check with stdlib [`sysconfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html) module:

```
import sysconfig
print(sysconfig.get_path("purelib"))
```

Some wheels might also install some scripts into the `bin` subdir.  You can also find this location using `sysconfig`:

```
print(sysconfig.get_path("scripts"))
```

Comment: Excellent..Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Try the show command:

`pip show sample.whl`

It will show the location of where it was installed.

Comment: Ohh okay...will check.